# I cannot create a new scheduled task for mumble

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-10

I'm trying to set a scheduled task in my computer so that the mumble client starts when I log on ; the task tries to start as planned but fails as follows :

> Task Scheduler failed to start "\Mumble" task for user
>   "computer\myuser". Additional Data: Error Value: 2147943140.

The command is

> "D:\Program Files (x86)\Mumble\mumble.exe"

with and without a mumble url as argument, with and without highest privilegies, as windows 10, windows 7 I'm at quite at loss as to how to deal with this, does anyone have an idea ?

(All other tasks work well, only mumble fails)

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround is to create a powershell script, say `start_mumble.ps1`, containing the following line (adjust the path as needed):

```
 Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mumble\mumble.exe" -WindowStyle Minimized
```

and schedule a task with action set as "Start a program" and settings

- *Program/script*: `powershell.exe`
- *Add arguments*: `\\path\to\start_mumble.ps1`

This approach worked for me on Windows 10. Make sure the invoked powershell can run scripts (see `Get-ExecutionPolicy` and `Set-ExecutionPolicy`).